# C# Entity Framework join, choose the exist value when joining 2 tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to write a method that check if a value already exist in my database, the value can exist in 1 of 2 tables (doesn't matter which one).

This is relevant part in my code

```
using (Context db = new Context())
{
    var _domain = (from s in db.Subscriptions
                   join a in db.Alias on s.Id equals a.Subscription_Id
                   where (s.Domain == domain || a.Alias_Domain == domain)
                   select /*if s.domain exist take s.domain, if a.alias domain exist take a.alias*/).FirstOrDefault();

    return _domain != null ? 1 : 0;
}
```

In the comment area /**/ I want to take the value that exists (can be either `s.Domain` or `a.Alias_Domain`).

Can someone please help me with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your post with some sample data (at least 10 rows from each table) and then show us, for a given value of `domain` what you want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number domains:

```
var count = 
    (from s in db.Subscriptions
     join a in db.Allias on s.Id equals a.Subscription_Id
     where (s.Domain == domain || a.Allias_Domain == domain)
     select s).Count();

return count > 0;
```